# IE, FireFox LDAP issues

Tags: ldap, internet-explorer, firefox

We have an intranet site, with no known updates pushed to the server over the weekend. This morning, when attempting to validate with LDAP credentials via single sign on in IE, we receive Access Denied due to invalid credentials.   However, FireFox works fine.  And so does Chrome. This is the case for every system on our network.

Are there any known issues that would cause IE8 to stop authenticating with the correct user name and password on an intranet site, while FireFox would continue to work?  To our knowledge, nothing has changed.

What are some things we should check for?  What could possibly cause IE to suddenly stop working?

Answer (score 0):

The LAN settings might be different for IE. Proxy settings could be set differently for IE.